# How to fetch the alerts from the prometheus federate

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have deployed the prometheus and alertmanager in region A and region B, and configured the federate job in the region A prometheus as below.

```
- job_name: 'multicluster'
  scrape_interval: 5m
  scrape_timeout: 1m
  honor_labels: true
  metrics_path: /federate
  params:
    'match[]':
      - '{__name__=~".+"}'
      - '{__name__=~"^job:.*"}'
      - '{job="prometheus"}'
      - '{job=~".+"}'
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['prometheus-route-amos-multicluster-monitoring.x.x.x.x:80']
      labels:
        platform: ireland
```

alertmanager configuration is as below

```
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m
route:
  group_by: ['service','status']
  group_wait: 30s
  group_interval: 30s
  repeat_interval: 1h
  receiver: ses-onix
  routes:
    - receiver: ses-onix
receivers:
  - name: ses-onix
    webhook_configs:
      - url: 'http://ses-amos-config-manager-x.x.x.x/alerts/INS'
        send_resolved: true
        http_config:
          basic_auth:
            username: 'username'
            password: 'password'
```

Now it is able to target the prometheus in region B.
Now the issue is when an event is triggered in region B main prometheus in region A is not able to fetch those events and logs also not showing any error details.

I have added the labels at node level for each cluster and added that in the prometheus expression

`up{job="etcd", kubernetes_cluster="london"} == 0` --> region A

`up{job="etcd", kubernetes_cluster="ireland"} == 0` --> region B

Now i'm expecting that when an event is triggered in region B, prometheus and alertmanager deployed in region A should be able to fetch it.